# Rows to comma separated list in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a requirement wherein the table structure I have looks like

```
ID                 Owner Id                NAME  
1                  20                      Name 1  
1                  21                      Name 2  
1                  34                      Name 3  
2                  10                      Name 4  
2                  12                      Name 5  
3                  100                     Name 6
```

I need a query that would give me the results as

```
ID                Owner ID                Name  
1                  20                     Name 1, Name2, Name 3  
2                  10                     Name4, Name5  
3                  100                    Name 6
```

Currently we do this on the codebehind, but I would ideally like to do this through SQL and see if that amounts to any performance improvement.

Comment: How are you deciding which `Owner Id` to show?

Comment: You'll have to specify the database for this question. there's no generic solution

Comment: @RedFilter looks like just the `min` one.

Comment: If you have code that currently takes data from SQL and produces the output you want, I suggest seeing why that code is so slow.  Making SQL do extra work other than simply returning a dataset is likely not going to fix your performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention your DBMS so I'm assuming PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT id, 
       min(owner_id) as lowest_id,
       string_agg(name, ', ') as name_list
FROM the_table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Its the first Owner ID and the DBMS is SQL.

Comment: Sorry guys forgot to mention I cannot use min here. The Darn DB ids are strings and its something like 'TNX-0000-CFT-0001'. It irks me when the primary key is a string but then thats how the system has been running for the last 10 years.

Comment: @user1313368: "SQL" is not a DBMS, it's a language. And `min()` *can* be used on a string value.